# event handler with jQuery UI autocomplete - Combobox

Tags: jquery, events, user-interface, autocomplete, combobox

I'm using the Combobox of jQuery UI's autocomplete script.
but now i have to implement a function, which hides every option of a second combobox which has not the same id as the selected one  after selecting an entry of the first one.

maybe a little bit clearer:

select one:
kundenauswahl

select two:
jobauswahl

if an option in "kundenauswahl" is selectet, the script should check the options of the second select/combobox wether they have the same ID than the selected option of "kundenauswahl" if so, those options schould be shown, if not those options should be hidden...

I don't know where i messed up, 
but with the script I wrote now, my page stays blank after loading...
no error Message in Firebug...

maybe someone could help?

I'm sure there are some mor failures inside this script...

I would be glad if s/o could help me out... :-(

here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

        $( "#kundenauswahl" ).combobox({
            selected: function(event, ui) {
                var optionid = document.getElementById("kundenauswahl")[document.getElementById("kundenauswahl").selectedIndex].id;
                changeoptions(optionid);
                return;
            } // selected
        }); // combobox

        $( "#jobauswahl" ).combobox({

        }); //combobox

    }); // ready(function())


function changeoptions(kundenid) {
    var idtoshow = kundenid;
    for (var counter = 0; counter < document.getElementsByName("joboption").length; counter++) {
        if (document.getElementsByName("joboption")[$counter].id == idtoshow) {
            document.getElementById(idtoshow).style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById(idtoshow).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo with the variable "$counter" instead of "counter".
also, if you are using jquery, why not go all the way?
For example, use

`$('#kundenauswahl option:selected')[0].id`

instead of:

`document.getElementById("kundenauswahl")[document.getElementById("kundenauswahl").selectedIndex].id`

Lastly, maybe you will have a problem when the page loads if no option is selected.

Comment: ok i've got the page working again - i've forgotten to define id's for the options. :-D but it still seems that the handler doesn't work...

Comment: what do you mean "the handler doesn't work"? is the selected function not being called? or does it not do what you think it should? BTW, 2 tricks to debug the situation is to use console.log("xxx") and alert("xxx"). the first will write text to the debug console (if your browser supports it) and the latter will throw the message to the screen. so you can tell where the interperter is and you can show different variables. Also, the chrome debugger is awesome IMHO